# Using Multiple filter-spec in Wildfly Logger

Tags: logging, filter, wildfly, handler, wildfly-10

I'm using **Wildfly 10** and I want store server log in a `json` file with some filters, here is my log:

```
{
    "msg": "\n[\"getDataMethod\" req. received]\n[password: ***]\n[prop2: value2]]\n",
    "field1": "value1"
}{
    "msg": "\n[call \"getDataMethod\"]\n[password: ***]\n[prop2: value2]]\n",
    "field2": "value2"
}{
    "msg": "full-XML SOAP request",
    "field3": "value3"
}{
    "msg": "\n[\"getDataMethod\" finished...]\n[password: ***]\n[prop2: value2]]\n",
    "field4": "value4"
}
```

But this log file has two problems:

1. the `msg` field contains critical information (like password) and I want filter them.
2. some of information is redundant and I don't want store them. (for example, nodes contains "req. received" or "call getDataMethod")

for solving problem #1, I write this `filter-spec` and remove all bucket with `regex`:

```xml
<logger category="org.somePackags.MyClass" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="INFO" />
    <filter-spec value="all(match(&quot;\\[(.*)\\]&quot;),substituteAll(&quot;\\[(.*)\\]&quot;, &quot; &quot;))" />
    <handlers>
        <handler name="JsonLog" />
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Now I want add rules to `filter-spec` to exclude nodes that match in problem #2, I read [FilterExpressions](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-FilterExpressions), But I don't know how to write Multiple `filter-spec`. any idea?

Comment: Which JSON formatter are you using?

Comment: It's generated by [Logstash/Gelf](https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/wildfly-json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`all`](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Admin_Guide.html#filter-expressions) filter will process each filter in the chain and if any of the filters in the chain deem the message unloggable, then the message isn't logged. The `all` with the `substituteAll` filter does seem to be the one you should be using. You'd just add more `substituteAll` filters in the chain.

What you'd need to figure out is the patterns to replace the data. You could remove the `match` as well it looks like it's just matching everything anyway.